# Keras construct GRU model for list of sententces

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
inputs = Input(shape=(None, 40)) 
embedding = Embedding(len(tok.word_index) + 1, 300,  trainable=True) 
titles_embed = embedding(inputs)
```

I have M samples, each one is a list of sentences in variable count. Each sentence has fixed 40 words. As `inputs`, `None`represents the variable count of sentences. 
And I use this embedding layer to vectorized each word to 300 dim.
After that, `titles_embed` has the shape of `(?, ?, 40, 300)`, where the first `?` is batch size, 
each sample in the batch is a paragraph, consisting of the second `?` number of sentences. 
Each sentence has `40` words, and finally `300` is the embedding size.

For the labelling part, each sentence has the label: 0 or 1, which indicate the label of each sentence, in the context of each paragraph.
I want to build a RNN model, such as GRU, to go thru these sentences in each paragraph and use every timestep encoder layer to predict the final label, as a binary classification task.

So I don't know how to process `titles_embed` next.
Anyone can give me some instruction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

quick answer:

you can simply add a recurrent layer, like GRU or LSTM, above your embedding layer

```
### example
inputs = Input(shape=(40)) 
embedding = Embedding(len(tok.word_index) + 1, 300,  trainable=True)(inputs)
gru = GRU(32, activation='relu')(embedding)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(gru)
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
```

further details:

first of all, you make a little confusion when you specify the dimensions. In your case keras, receives as input sequences of text that you must integer encoded and padded in order to have the same length (I suppose you have already done). our input dimension is (n_sample, sequence_leght), so in the input layer, we have to specify only the feature dimension in input (40). keras process the data in batches so during training the dimension will be (batch_dim, sequence_leght). the embedding layer 'map' the integer received as input associating a trainable vector. our dimension in this section will be (batch_dim, seq_len, emb_dim). on this output we can add a recurrent layer.

I think that there are lot of resources available on the internet which explain how to use embeddings and recurrent layer in NLP, so you have a great number of resources available